# this.QueryString (NameValueCollection) access Form1 - from another class

Tags: c#, class, asp.net-4.0

i have made a helper Method using it to modify Query Strings, for testing and debugging

the only problem now is that i would like to make it as a Class in my 
C# collection helper-class

the method is working perfectly now , but as i am still "fresh" .net developer

i couldn't figure out how to use 
`this.Request.QueryString` to access current `partial class` - form (form1) 
values when it's inside a separated public static or non static class

this is the code , you're free to use it (:

```
public void QsModify(string action, string NewP_Value, string CurQS_ParamName, string         NewQs_paramName=null, bool redirectWithNewQuerySettings=false)
{

#region <<=========== reflect to readonly & set QueriString ReadOnly - false ============>>





// reflect to readonly property 
PropertyInfo isReadOnly = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// make collection editable 
isReadOnly.SetValue(this.Request.QueryString, false, null);

#endregion
switch (action)
{
    case ModAQs_Remove:
        if (notEmptyQs()) 
        this.Request.QueryString.Remove(CurQS_ParamName);
        break;
    case ModAQs_Replace:
        this.Request.QueryString.Remove(CurQS_ParamName);
        this.Request.QueryString.Add(NewQs_paramName, NewP_Value);
        break;
    case ModAQs_EditValue:
        this.Request.QueryString.Set(CurQS_ParamName, NewP_Value);
        break;

    case ModAQs_Add:
        this.Request.QueryString.Add(NewQs_paramName, NewP_Value);
        break;

}


#region <<=========== joining Full Path & queryString then Redirection  ============>>


string seperator = "?";
UrlPath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
UrlPathAndQuery = string.Join(seperator, UrlPath, this.Request.QueryString);
isReadOnly.SetValue(this.Request.QueryString, true, null);

if (redirectWithNewQuerySettings)
{

    Response.Redirect(UrlPathAndQuery);
}
#endregion
}
```

how do i make it into a class that will be able to access any project i am working on 
not knowing what the form name will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["qs_key"];
```

You can use it either in static or non-static contexts.

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply , gonna try implement it now . i will notify results

Comment: had to move quite a few bools and strings , though made it , all done , and it works like charm ! , all variables including the code itself is now left out of main page , thats a side efect of the main one which is , the ease of use , then you get tidy page also, thanks for your help Cj